# Problem with plugin of Flipper version 0.165.0

Tags: react-native, plugins, flipper

I have problem when upgrade Flipper to newest version and can't use default plugin of Flipper. Any idea for that because i have research but not see anyone same this problem.
I use M1 pro with chip apple silicon.

Thanks for reading and feel free to comment.

[image: missing plugin of Flipper version 0.165.0]
[image]

Comment: I am also facing this. Downgrade to [previous version](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases/tag/v0.164.0) which seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks @ArnabXD for that and create issues in github. I have downgrade and it working. Hope Flipper team can check and fix it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

The answer above by Arnab is correct, just downgrade the flipper version to 0.164. It saved me falling back from using flipper.

Comment: How do you downgrade a flipper version on Mac m1?

Comment: You can find the older versions in flipper archives